# How to sum up to column specified in other cell in Drive Sreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a SUM formula that covers a range defined in other cells.

For example, I have cell B2 with value: E

Current formula in cell B3 is:

```
=SUM('Sheet 2'!C5:E5)
```

I want to modify the formula to sum up to column E defined in B2. I tried different options with no results, some of them were:

```
=SUM("'Sheet 2'!C5:"&B2&"5")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet 2'!C5:"&B2&"5"))
```